# merge groupby results directly back to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,1,10],[1,2,20],[1,3,50],[2,1,15],[2,2,20],[2,3,30],[3,1,40],[3,2,70]],columns=['id1','id2','x'])


   id1  id2   x
0    1    1  10
1    1    2  20
2    1    3  50
3    2    1  15
4    2    2  20
5    2    3  30
6    3    1  40
7    3    2  70
```

The dataframe is sorted along the two ids. Suppose I'd like to know the value of x of the FIRST observation within each group of `id1` observations. The result would be like

```
id1 id2 x   first_x
1   1   10  10
1   2   30  10
1   3   50  10
2   1   15  15
2   2   20  15
2   3   30  15
3   1   40  40
3   2   70  40
```

How do I achieve this 'subscripting'? Ideally, the new column would be filled for each observation.

I thought along the lines of

```
df['first_x'] = df.groupby(['id1'])[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest is [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df['first_x'] = df.groupby('id1')['x'].transform('first')
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['first_x'] = df['id1'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id1').set_index('id1')['x'])

print (df)
   id1  id2   x  first_x
0    1    1  10       10
1    1    2  20       10
2    1    3  50       10
3    2    1  15       15
4    2    2  20       15
5    2    3  30       15
6    3    1  40       40
7    3    2  70       40
```

First is shortest and fastest solution:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcde') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': np.random.randint(10000,size=N),
                   'x':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values('id1').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [179]: %timeit df.join(df.groupby(['id1'])['x'].first(), on='id1', how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='_first')
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [180]: %%timeit
     ...: first_xs = df.groupby(['id1']).first().to_dict()['x']
     ...: 
     ...: df['first_x'] = df['id1'].map(lambda id: first_xs[id])
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 524 ms per loop

In [181]: %timeit df['first_x'] = df.groupby('id1')['x'].transform('first')
10 loops, best of 3: 54.9 ms per loop

In [182]: %timeit df['first_x'] = df['id1'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id1').set_index('id1')['x'])
10 loops, best of 3: 142 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,1,10],[1,2,20],[1,3,50],[2,1,15],[2,2,20],[2,3,30],[3,1,40],[3,2,70]],columns=['id1','id2','x'])
df = df.join(df.groupby(['id1'])['x'].first(), on='id1', how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='_first')
```

Comment: Am I right that this yields the minimum value of `x'? I'd rather have the first value (which happens to correspond the min in my example).

Comment: Yeap, no problem! I modified the group by function to use first() instead!

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way avoid the `x` column to be renamed? I have a huge dataframe and can't regularly rename columns

Comment: Yeap, I got what you need! Just use join with a pandas series instead :)

Answer (score 1):

As you need to consider the entire dataframe when building values for each row, you need an intermediate step.

The following gets your `first_x` value using a group by, then uses that as a map to add a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,1,10],[1,2,20],[1,3,50],[2,1,15],[2,2,20],[2,3,30],[3,1,40],[3,2,70]],columns=['id1','id2','x'])

first_xs = df.groupby(['id1']).first().to_dict()['x']

df['first_x'] = df['id1'].map(lambda id: first_xs[id])
```